# error with RBGL package in R

Tags: r, graph, package

I want to install the RGBL package in bioconductor to perform some graph algorithms.

I updated R to the latest version 3.2.0, and installed the package as instructed on http://www.bioconductor.org/

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("RBGL")
```

It was installed successfully, then I tried to run

```
  library(graph)
  library(RBGL)

  x<- strongComp(graph)
```

and returns this error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘isDirected’ for signature ‘"igraph"’
```

Here's the traceback

```
> traceback()
4: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
       sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
3: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
   {
       methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
       if (length(methods) == 1L) 
           return(methods[[1L]])
       else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
           cnames <- paste0("\"", vapply(classes, as.character, 
               ""), "\"", collapse = ", ")
           stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
               sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
       }
       else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
           domain = NA)
   })(list("igraph"), function (object) 
   standardGeneric("isDirected"), <environment>)
2: isDirected(g)
1: strongComp(graph)
```

My system is Windows 32-bit.

I'm not sure if this is enough information. Please let me know if any other information needed.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

I used the `igraph` packaged to create the graph object from an edge list with weight

```
  library(igraph)
  graph<- graph.data.frame(edge.list[,c(2:4)],directed=TRUE)
```

I'm not very good with generating random number, here's a reproducible example for my graph

```
set.seed(123)
edge.list<-cbind(seq(10),c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5,5,5),c(2,2,3,5,4,3,4,4,4,2),
            runif(10, 1, 30))
colnames(edge.list) <-c("ID","V1","V2","weight")
```

Comment: Please make this error [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). How is the variable `graph` defiled/created? You appears to be passing in an `igraph` object rather than a `graph` object.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added the example in my post. I'm not sure what's the difference between an `igraph` object  and a `graph` object . How do I create a `graph` object from an edge list in R then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to make a `graph` object, not an `igraph` object.

Here's how I might transform your `edge.list` into the form that `graph` expects.

```
rawEL <- data.frame(source = as.character(edge.list[,1]),
    edges = as.character(edge.list[,2]),
    weights = edge.list[,3], stringsAsFactors=F
)
V <- unique(c(rawEL$source, rawEL$edges))
edL <- lapply(
    split(
       rawEL[,-1], 
       factor(edge.list[,1], levels=V)
    ), as.list
)
gr <- graphNEL(V, edL, "directed")
plot(gr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry that the sample data I gave was not a good sample. My data actually have very few nodes but many edges, there are also multi-edges exist. I read the help page on `graphNEL` says this function doesn't support multi-edges. Since I'm not familiar with the `graph` package. Could you please tell me what other function would be suitable for this situation? I'll also update my sample data to reflect this feature. Thanks!

Comment: Also I have another column of edge attributes, how do I represent it in the `graph` object? Thanks!